# Too many connections magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Before Flagging it as Duplicate.

Please Go trough the question once.

I have a Magento application and MySQL Db is running on a dedicated server and problem is I have set the max-connections value to 500 and when user tries to access the website we are getting

> " SQL State [HY000] Too many connections error".

When I check the database with mysqladmin tool | max_used_connections didn't even reach 110. But in reality we are not even having 35-40 active connections from the application server. Increasing max-connections maybe a solution but DB is not even using 110 connections.

This error comes from the same user and same location.

Any thoughts and comments are much appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend starting here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/too-many-connections.html  If your dedicated server is a Windows machine, make note of the limitation on Windows. The "Too many connections" error can also occur when the disk is full.

Comment: Spencer thank you but this is centos linux machine with 55gb ram

Comment: it's can be drive space problem

Comment: We are having ample amount of space on DB server more than 200 gb free space. bxN5 are you refering to Magento App's disk space

Comment: I have gone through Slow query logs for any unusual long running queries  which might be blocking the resources but found nothing. This happens to only one user.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. We found that PHP settings were using persistent connections and making MySQL error out.